# MonthCalendar control throws "Value does not fall within the expected range."

Tags: vb.net, monthcalendar

This is strange.  I decided to play with the monthcalendar control.  All I did what put it on a form with no code behind it.  When I try to click on it to change a date, I get an error.

"Value does not fall within the expected range."

I think I would like to use this control but have no idea what is going wrong.

Comment: Please share what you done until now ... some code for example

Comment: I have an entire windows application but as far as the monthcalendar is concerned, all I did was put it on a blank form, run the app and click on the calendar.  I've tried clearing the date selection properties and various other things but it always gives the error.

Comment: The only thing that I can think of is that I am not in the US so I use a date format of dd/mm/yyyy.  Could that be it?  Am I really the only person experiencing this?  I am using vs2012 update 3.

Comment: Nope, not my regional settings.  I just tested as US but same error.